# How to make multer save images to disk?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, multer

So I've been trying to make multer save images data on disk and the images mimetypes, names and paths to the folder on disk on Mongo. What i have now looks like this:

**Multer setup:**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, '/public/images/uploads'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    fileFilter (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg\jpg\png)$/)) {
            cb(new Error('Only upload jpg and png files.'));
        }

        cb(undefined, true);
    }
});
```

**The route to upload images:**

```
router.post('/upload/:userid', upload.single('photo'), uploadPhoto);
```

**Then this bit from the controller to save images details on Mongo:**

```
const newPhoto = new Photo({
    photo: {
        mimetype,
        photoUrl: `images/uploads/${name}`,
        name,
    },
});
```

**The axios call to the 'uploads' endpoint:**

```
await axios.post(
                `${baseUrl}/api/photo/upload/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'))._id}`,
                formData,
                { headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }},
            ).then(response => setPhotoUrls([response.data.photoUrl, ...photoUrls]));
```

So the backend part works fine, as it saves the desired data on Mongo, but the images still don't get saved on disk. How can I make multer save the selected images on disk?

Answer (score 0):

create seprate folder for multer like `multerHelper.js`

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    fs.mkdirsSync(__dirname + '/uploads/images'); // fs.mkdirsSync will create folders if it does not exist
    cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads/images');
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
   console.log(file);

    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
 }
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

let createUserImage = upload.single('photo');

let multerHelper = {
    createUserImage,
}

module.exports = multerHelper;
```

In your routes import multerhelper file

```
const multerHelper = require("../helpers/multer_helper");

router.post('/upload/:userid',multerHelper, uploadPhoto);
```